# I'm trying to implement MVVM Architecture, but this error is consuming me... (ViewModelProvider)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

just it's me trying to implement MVVM architecture with Kotlin. I need to use ViewModelProvider to init my instance and I'm getting this error...
Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Does your `AssignmentViewModel` extend `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a no of options to to instantiate viewmodels.

Now You can now use the ViewModelProvider constructor directly.

`private val assignmentViewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(AssignmentViewModel::class.java)`

If you use `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$Version` in the library you can do this directly

`private val assignmentViewModel: AssignmentViewModel by viewModels()`

If you're using a viewModelFactory

`private val assignmentViewModel=  ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(AssignmentViewModel ::class.java)`

and `private val assignmentViewModel: AssignmentViewModel by viewModels { viewModelFactory }` respectively

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin the easiest way to incorporate a ViewModel in your code is via a [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html):

Activity/Fragment:

```
    val assignmentViewModel: AssignmentViewModel by viewModels()
```

Fragment:

```
    val assignmentViewModel: AssignmentViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

The latter allows you to share data between fragments, since `activityViewModels` scopes it to the Activity.

See [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) for more information.